# Generating Hermite polynomial with coefficient recurrance relation algorithm

Tags: numerical-methods, orthogonal-polynomials

I am writing a math paper for my numerical analysis class about orthogonal Hermite polynomials. I want to implement the algorithm for generating the "probabilist's Hermite polynomials":

$$
\begin{align*}
H_{0}(x) &=1\\
H_{1}(x) &=x\\
H_{2}(x) &=  x^{2} - 1 \\
H_{3}(x) &=  x^{3} - 3 x \\
& \vdots
\end{align*}
$$.

I found an algorithm on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Recurrence_relation) for generating Hermite polynomials using the recurrence relation
$$
\begin{equation}
a_{n+1,k} =
\begin{cases}
-na_{n-1,k} \quad k =0 \\
a_{n,k-1} - na_{n-1,k} \quad k>0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
where $a_{n,k}$ is the $k^{\text{th}}$ coefficient for the $n^{\text{th}}$ Hermite polynomial starting with $a_{0,0}=1$, $a_{1,0}=0$, and $a_{1,1}=1$.

My problem is that I am having a hard time finding a proof of this algorithm or at least a description of how the algorithm is derived. I am mostly looking for a source to cite in my paper, but if someone who knows a strategy to prove this, maybe starting with recurrence relation $H_{n+1}(x) = 2xH_n(x) - 2nH_{n-1}(x)$? Any help would is appreciated.

Comment: if you are looking for a proof, then [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net) is probably a better option

Comment: Cross-posted as https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417922/generating-hermite-polynomial-with-coefficient-recurrance-relation-algorithm/418038#418038